# Need a hint for sequence convergence homework

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Hello and thank you for spending time to help me in advance!

The following exercise/homework problem has been giving me a difficult time and I am wondering if there is something simple that I am just not seeing at the moment.

[image: taylor-exercise]

I thought I could find the maximum sequence by just assuming that none of the $d$s are equal to $0$. Thus $a_n$ becomes $a_n= 2^{-1}+...+2^{-n}$. Then I rewrote this as the sum from $k=1$ to $k=n$ of $2^{-k}$. I wasn't able to figure out how to continue, though.

Comment: What is giving you difficulty?  What is the maximum possible sequence $d_n$ such that the value of $a_n$ is maximized?

Comment: Just note that for all $k,u$, $\sum_{i=u}^k2^i=2^{k-u+1}-2^u$.  This is an easy identity to verify, if verification is needed.  In particular, if $u\le k\le 0$, the identity still holds, and all that is needed is a note of why it is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably note that $0 \leq a_{n} = d_{1}\cdot 2^{-1} + ... + d_{n}\cdot 2^{-n} \leq 1\cdot2^{-1} + ... + 1\cdot 2^{-n} \leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{i}} \leq 1$. Note that since $[0,1]$ is closed and $0 \leq a_{n} \leq 1\; \forall\; n \in \mathbb{Z}$, it follows that the sequence converges to some point in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a similar problem: let $\{d_n\}$ be a sequence of $0,1,\dots,9$'s, and define a sequence of $\{a_n\}$ by

$$
a_n = d_110^{-1} + d_210^{-2} + \dots + d_n10^{-n}
$$

so basically, $a_n$ is a number with decimal expansion
$$
a_n = 0.d_1d_2\dots d_n
$$

Note that if I allowed $d_n$'s to be digits bigger than 9, the formula I wrote for $a_n$ doesn't give a valid decimal expansion.